# How to load JSON data into a class or array of classes in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, class, observable

Basically what I want is to load my JSON response into an array of classes, but with the Angular http getting deprecated I'm having some trouble with the HttpClient, all other version I've seen use the .map method which is no longer present(only after pipe).

My JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "Id": 1002469,
      "Summary": null,
      "StartDate": "2018-12-11T23:00:00",
      "EndDate": "2018-12-31T23:00:00",
...
```

I have two classes one ListSearch and a List class.

Below is my code for the API request:

```
getList() {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/list/' + this.token)
    ;
  }

this.apisService.getList()
      .subscribe((list: any) => {
        this.listSearch = list;
        console.log(list);
        },
        error => console.log('Error.')
      );
```

This prints out my response JSON perfectly. But when I try to put all this into a class or array, it's going to be undefined or it gets the data something like this:

```
ListSearch {0: "{", 1: "
", 2: "↵", 3: " ", 4: " ", 5: """, 6: "l", 7: "i", 8: "s", 9: "t", 10: """, 11: ":", 12: " ", 13: "[", 14: "
", 15: "↵", 16: " ", 17: " ", 18: " ", 19: " ", 20: "{", 21: "
", 22: "↵", 23: " ", 24: " ", 25: " ", 26: " ", 27: " ", 28: " ", 29: """, 30: "I", 31: "d", 32: """, 33: ":", 34: " ", 35: "1", 36: "0", 37: "0", 38: "2", 39: "4", 40: "6", 41: "9", 42: ",", ...
```

My code for the result above:

```
this.apisService.getList()
      .subscribe((list: ListSearch) => {
        const a = new ListSearch().deserialize(list);
        console.log(a);
        },
        error => console.log('Error.')
      );
```

Do you have any suggestion how could I make this work?

**UPDATE:**

Made the following interfaces(using this: https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/):

```
export interface List {
    list?: (ListEntity)[] | null;
  }
  export interface ListEntity {
    Id: number;
```

And the following code still returns *undefined* ...

```
this.apisService.getList()
  .subscribe((list: ListSearch) => {

    console.log(list.list);
```

**UPDATE2:**

The following code returns the first character of the json "*{*"

```
this.apisService.getList()
      .subscribe((list: List[]) => {

        console.log(list[0]);
...
```

**UPDATE3:**

I think I'm close to get it right:

```
  this.apisService.getList()
  .subscribe((data: ListSearch) => this.listSearch = {
    list: data['list']
    },
```

It now returns:

```
{list: undefined}list: undefined__proto__: Objectconstructor: ƒ ...
```

****************** **SOLUTION:** ******************

Finally! 
I've created a simple Object:

```
a: Object;
```

Then did the following:

```
this.apisService.getList()
    .subscribe((data: string) => {
        this.a = JSON.parse(data);
        this.listSearch = <List>this.a;
```

And it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The right way:**

*Interface:*

```
export interface IEmployee {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

*Service*:

```
getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
        return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);
    }
```

*Component*:

```
public employees = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees()
    .subcribe(
        data => this.employees = data
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you JSON file starts with {, the HTTPClient is reading it as singel object. Change the service code to below:

```
getList() {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/list/' + this.token);
  }

this.apisService.getList()
  .subscribe((list: any) => {
    this.listSearch = list.list;
    console.log(list);
    },
    error => console.log('Error.')
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I try to do something with "this.listSearch" it says it's "undefined".

Comment: Tried this also: `.subscribe((list: any) => {
        this.listSearch = list;

        console.log(this.listSearch);
        this.listSearch.list.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element.Id);
        });` but returned the next error: _ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined_

Comment: can you post the log after this method: this.apisService.getList()
      .subscribe((list: any) => {
        console.log(list);
        },
        error => console.log('Error.')
      );

Comment: Yes, if I do this, I get the json printed out: `{
  "list": [
    {
      "Id": 1002469,
      "Summary": null,
      "StartDate": "2018-12-11T23:00:00",
      "EndDate": "2018-12-31T23:00:00", ... `

Comment: can you please try console.log(Object.keys(list)) or console.log(JSON.stringify(list)) and see what the output is

Comment: Yes, the output is(Object.keys): `(498) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", …]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 399]
[400 … 497]
length: 498
__proto__: Array(0)` it's weird

Comment: stringify: `"{\r\n  \"list\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Id\": 1002469,\r\n      \"Summary\": null,\r\n `

Comment: looks like the service response is not correct, to over come this we can try something like this console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list).replace("\r\n ","")).list)

Comment: The output for this is simply `undefined` .

Comment: my Bad, I had use "List" instead of "list". Updated my comment, please try

Comment: Yes, I've noticed, but either way it's still `undefined` .

Comment: can you save the stringify response in a file and attach it here. Let me try to see whats happening :)

Comment: here is what worked for me. console.log(JSON.parse(list.replace(' ','').replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "").list). You can refer the stckblitz in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twkmcu

Answer (score 0):

You should crate a Model interface for those class firstly, then

```
this.apisService.getList()
  .subscribe((list: ListSearch[]) => {
    const value = list;
    console.log(value);
    },
    (error: any) => console.log('Error.')
  );
```